# ValidationMessageFor not working after TryValidateModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view model that contains a collection of objects.  My action can modify some of the those objects, and then I need to re-validate the model.  I use:

```
 ModelState.Clear();
            foreach (QuestionDTO d in model.Questions)
                TryValidateModel(d);
```

The problem is that when the modelstate is not valid, the ValidationMessageFor no longer displays.  It does work when I use the default validation without clearing it.  The errors are showing up in a validationsummary.

In the cshtml page I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Questions[i])
    }
```

I have an editor template for the questions. An example of the code in the editor template:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.Raw(Model.QuestionText)<br />
        @Html.MyCustomTextBoxFor(t => Model.AnswerText, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnswerText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
```

I've tried using TryValidateModel(model.Questions) but it doesn't seem to validate because the model is then valid.  I feel like I need to just do something different with the TryValidateModel.  Any help?

Comment: Validation is performed by readng the values from the request. Not sure what your mean by your action can modify values, but that will not affect `ModelState`

Comment: And the code in your view should be just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Questions)`. No loop.